# How to determine size limits of variable?

Tags: c, variables, limits

I'm struggling with determining edge-sizes of each variable. I can't understand the following problem.

To get maximum value of char for example, I use: `~ 0 >> 1`
Which should work like this:

1. transfer 0 to binary: 0000 0000 (I assume that char is stored on 8
   bits)
2. negate it: 1111 1111 (now I'm out of char max size)
3. move one place right: 0111 1111 (I get 127 which seems to be correct)

Now I want to present this result using `printf` function.
Why exactly do I have to use cast like this:
 `printf("%d\n", (unsigned char)(~0) >> 1)`?

I just don't get it. I assume that it has something to do with point 2 when I get out of char range, but I'm not sure.

I will be grateful if you present me more complex explanation to this problem.

Comment: The minimum and maximum values of data types are defined in `<limits.h>`.

Comment: Er... How exactly did you expect to use `~ 0 >> 1` to obtain the maximum value of `char`, when the expression `~ 0 >> 1` does not include a single reference to type `char`??? Why should `~ 0 >> 1` give you maximum value of `char`, and not , say, maximum value of `short` or `long`?

Comment: @AnT: That makes no difference, as the expression will always be executed as `int` (unless any operand has a higher rank).

Comment: @Olaf: That's not my point. Difference or no difference, the expression is not tied in any way to the desired target type. It should be obvious to the OP that (regardless of any other rules of the language), the expression cannot magically "know" what target type the OP had in mind. It cannot produce the max value of `char` unless it mentions `char` in some way, explicitly or implicitly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please don't use these kinds of tricks. They might work on ordinary machines but they are possibly unportable and hard to understand. Instead, use the symbolic constants from the header file `limits.h` which contains the size limits for each of the basic types. For instance, `CHAR_MAX` is the upper bound for a `char`, `CHAR_MIN` is the lower bound. Further limits for the numeric types declared in `stddef.h` and `stdint.h` can be found in `stdint.h`.

---

Now for your question: Arithmetic is done on values of type `int` by default, unless you cause the operands involved to have a different type. This happens for various reasons, like one of the variables involved having a different type or you using a iteral of different type (like `1.0` or `1L` or `1U`). Even more importantly, the type of an arithmetic expression promotes from the inside to the outside. Thus, in the statement

```
char c = 1 + 2 + 3;
```

The expression `1 + 2 + 3` is evaluated as type `int` and only converted to `char` immediately before assigning. Even more important is that in the C language, you can't do arithmetic on types smaller than `int`. For instance, in the expression `c + 1` where `c` is of type `char`, the compiler inserts an *implicit conversion* from `char` to `int` before adding one to `c`. Thus, a statement like

```
c = c + 1;
```

actually behaves like this in C:

```
c = (char)((int)c + 1);
```

Thus, `~0 >> 1` actually evaluates to `0xffffffff` (-1) on a usual 32 bit architecture because the type `int` usually has 32 bits and right shifting of signed types usually shifts sign bits so the most significant bit becomes a one. Casting to `unsigned char` cause *truncation*, with the result being `0xff` (255). All arguments but the first to `printf` are part of a *variable argument list* which is a bit complicated but basically means that all types *smaller* than `int` are converted to `int`, `float` is converted to `double` and all other types are left unchanged.

Now, how can we get this right? On an ordinary machine with two's complement and no padding bits one could use expressions like these to compute the largest and smallest `char`, assuming `sizeof (char) < sizeof (int)`:

```
(1 << CHAR_BIT - 1) - 1; /* largest char */
-(1 << CHAR_BIT - 1);    /* smallest char */
```

For other types, this is going to be slightly more difficult since we need to avoid overflow. Here is an expression that works for all signed integer types on an ordinary machine, where `type` is the type you want to have the limits of:

```
(type)(((uintmax_t)1 << sizeof (type) * CHAR_BIT - 1) - 1) /* largest */
(type)-((uintmax_t)1 << sizeof (type) * CHAR_BIT - 1)      /* smallest */
```

For an unsigned type `type`, you could use this to get the maximum:

```
~(type)0
```

Please notice that all these tricks should *not* appear in portable code.

Comment: On my machine, `intmax_t` and `size_t` are declared in `stdint.h`.

Comment: @cad The *types* are declared in `stdint.h` but the *size limits* are in `limits.h`.

Comment: @cad: `size_t` shoud be defined in `stddef.h` actually.

Comment: I know this, but it was kind of an excercise for understanding variables'  sizes.

Comment: Just to add that if recommended warnings are enabled (here: `-Wconversion` for gcc), the compiler should complain about possible truncation when assigning an integer expression to a (very likely) smaller type like `char` without explicit cast.

Comment: @FUZxxl According to your response, shouldn't it be `((1 << CHAR_BIT -1) - 1)` largest and `-(1 << CHAR_BIT - 1)` smallest?

Comment: @threaz Yes, that's a typo. I'm fixing it right now.

Answer (score 2):

The exact effect of your actions is different from what you assumed.

`0` is not `0000 0000`. `0` has type `int`, which means that it is most likely `0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000`, depending on how many bits `int` has on your platform. (I will assume 32-bit `int`.)

Now, `~0` is, expectedly, `1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111`, which still has type `int` and is a negative value.

When you shift it to the right, the result is implementation-defined. Right-shifting negative signed integer values in C does not guarantee that you will obtain `0` in the sign bit. Quite the opposite, most platforms will actually replicate the sign bit when right-shifting. Which means that `~0 >> 1` will still give you `1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111`.

Note, that even if you do this on a platform that shifts-in a `0` into the sign bit when right-shifting negative values, you will still obtain `0111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111`, which is in general case not the maximum value of `char` you were trying to obtain.

If you want to make sure that a right-shift operation shifts-in `0` bits from the left, you have to either 1) shift an *unsigned* bit-pattern or 2) shift a *signed, but positive* bit-pattern. With negative bit patterns you risk running into the sign-extending behavior, meaning that for negative values `1` bits would be shifted-in from the left instead of `0` bits.

Since C language does not have shifts that would work in the domain of `[unsigned/signed] char` type (the operand is promoted to `int` anyway before the shift), what you can do is make sure that you are shifting a positive `int` value and make sure that your initial bit-mask has the correct number of `1`s in it. That is exactly what you achieve by using `(unsigned char) ~0` as the initial mask. `(unsigned char) ~0` will participate in the shift as a value of type `int` equal to `0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1111 1111` (assuming 8-bit `char`). After the shift you will obtain `0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0111 1111`, which is exactly what you were trying to obtain.

Answer (score 1):

That only works with unsigned integers. For signed integers, right shifting a negative number and the behaviour of in bit-wise inversion is *implementation defined*. Not only it depends on the representation of negative values, but also what CPU instruction the compiler uses to perform the right-shift (some CPUs do not have arithmetic (right) shift for instance.

So, unless you make additional constraints for your implementation, it is not possible to determine the limits of signed integers. This implies there is no completely portable way (for signed integers).

Note that whether `char` is signed or unsigned is also implementation defined and that `(unsigned char)(~0) >> 1` is subject to *integer promotions*, so it will not yield a character result, but an `int`. (which makes the format specifier correct - allthough presumably unintended).

Use [`limits.h`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.2.4.2.1) to get macros for your implementation's integer limits. This file has to be provided by any standard-compliant C compiler.